# Secure .php file, called via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, nginx

Our clients use our free service using code like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>id='example'; width='640'; height='480';</script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/example.js'></script>
```

example.js looks like this:

```
if (typeof (width) == "undefined") {
    var width = '100%';
}
if (typeof (height) == "undefined") {
    var height = '100%';
}
if (typeof (p) == "undefined") {
    var p = '0';
}
if (typeof (c) == "undefined") {
    var c = '0';
}
if (typeof (stretching) == "undefined") {
    var stretching = 'uniform';
}
document.write('<iframe allowfullscreen width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="http://example.com/examplefile.php?id=' + id + '&p=' + p + '&c=' + c + '&stretching=' + stretching + '"></iframe>');
```

The problem is people are leeching examplefile.php. We tried using secure_link with nginx, and it worked great, but only for clients who are able to use PHP code in their sites, generating a random secure token with a key. Some other clients can only embed HTML code. Is there a way to secure the examplefile.php or maybe change the examplefile.php name randomly, and verify it against our server to stop the leeching?

Maybe using jQuery? We need to be able to make sure examplefile.php is begin called by this JavaScript code and not added manually as an iframe from external sites.

Comment: If client's server have only static content – there's no way to make it really secure. You can use even some kind of whitelist in nginx which domain can iframe your page (Content-Security-Policy), but that's easy to break.

It is possible that one of your clients will count against you? If client can hurt only himself – maybe I can find solution. But if client can be that bad guy and give other people his "password" to your service – there's no way to make it secure. So - it is possible to give users "accounts" and don't worry about that how they'll use it?

Comment: Yes, this is an option. Looks like i will have to implement an account system, whats your idea if i do?

Comment: I've been up too many hours... Sorry in advance for any unclear sentence ;) My idea is now only idea – I've not even test it, but I think it could work. I'll write it as answer, because it's too long for comment.

Comment: Ok, maybe here. I'm afraid that my idea's wrong. At least – it's complicated a bit. But the second core of it was ``$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']``. Only that is too weak, but with other walls it could be enough to protect from most people.

Comment: I'd love to read your idea. Did you write it as answer? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to ensure you're the only one using this resource.
One way to do it is to replace `example.js` with a generated JS file `example.php`.

This file will have two responsibilities:

1. Verifying the request against your server
2. Output plain JS content, as if it were a JS file (with appropriate header data).

**Update**

This is my approach to be specific:

By using the example.php file (instead of the example.js), each time a user loads the file, initialize a unique session token for the client, in which you will validate immediately in examplefile.php. This way you can make sure (to some level) the request came from example.php

Comment: Thanks but then, they will add this php file and we will be at the same situation than before?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the JavaScript with a AJAX request that sends a custom HTTP Request Header with a token. Upon validating the token your server would respond with the URL for use in the iframe. This solution provides you with the opportunity to control the URL so you could randomise it.

An alternative is to send the request to a URL that indicates your intent to access the resource. It could respond with a session cookie which will be carried by the subsequent request for the iframe link.

Here's some vanilla JavaScript to get you started with the AJAX request.

```
var myURL = 'https://www.example.com/path/',
    myCustomKey = 'Custom-Header',
    myCustomValue = 'Custom-Token-Value',
    myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

// open request so that custom header can be added
myRequest.open('GET', myURL, true);
// set custom header for request
myRequest.setRequestHeader(myCustomKey, myCustomValue);

myRequest.onload = function () {
    // Request finished. Do processing here.
    if (myRequest.status === 200) {
        // Request was successful
        // use the response
        console.log(myRequest.response);
    }
};

myRequest.send(null);
```

You will have to configure the server to support CORS. See https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I like this solution, but do you think people leeching the content will be able to send the same header, and get the file anyways? Also, i'm not sure how to implement this. Can you help me more with this example in my case? Thanks!!!

Comment: No solution is going to be completely secure. If you are concerned about replay attacks, then generate an encrypted token that is unique to each domain and includes the referrer domain and a timestamp. The server side then needs to verify that the timestamp is within a predetermined time window and that the referrer is from the encrypted domain. Look into HMAC-SHA authentication, it's how Amazon restricts access to resources on S3.